# jquery click event in a repeat region

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

i am trying to educate mysely with jQuery by converting some old javascript code into the jQuery syntax but i seam to have hit a stumbling block, i am not very experienced with this language so please be easy on me.....lol.

I am trying to convert this to jQuery:

```
function getData (id) {
    document.form1.numID.value = id;
    document.form1.submit();
}
```

The id is passed by a javascript onClick event, this is then added to a hidden field and submitted with the form. The problem i am having is that when i bind jQuery to the click event for the div that was clicked i only ever get the first item in the repeat region to work, the rest do nothing, i have included the jquery i have gathered so far, i am assuming its because the divs are all named the same within the repeat region?;

```
$('#Editor').click(function () {
    var id = $('#this').attr('value');
    alert('You Clicked Edit Job '+id+'..!!');
});
```

I have just echoed this to an alert whilst i figure how to do this, the rest i can do just cannot seam to figure this out even after googling. Once i figure this i am then going to convert the old asp app into an ajax event.

`<div id="Editor" value="123">Some database info displayed on the page</div>`
`<div id="Editor" value="456">Some more data info displayed on the page</div>`
`<div id="Editor" value="789">Even more info displayed from the database</div>`

I have edited all the data out from the database, these divs are created based on the number of records returned from the database, i want to pass the "value" to another page where the id is used to get the item clicked. Hope this explains my dilemma a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id should be uniq!  and using value attribute in DIV it's not standard..

```
<div id="Editor">
    <div class="field" id="123">Some database info displayed on the page</div>
    <div class="field" id="456">Some more data info displayed on the page</div>
    <div class="field" id="789">Even more info displayed from the database</div>
</div>



 $('#Editor').click(function (e) {
        var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
        alert('You Clicked Edit Job '+id+'..!!');
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mnsJT/2/

Comment: Hi thanks for the speedy reply, but is that not the same as what i had, just using a different attr name?

Comment: check how I get the id, by $(this)

Comment: my apologies, i think i pasted in some wierd code in my original post, i did have the same as you with the $(this) and not my original, and that is my issue, as the click event is bound to the div Editor when the repeat region gets fired and all the data is displayed from the record set all the divs are named the same and i can only get the event to fire for the first div listed, the others do nothing? is there a way to get jquery to distinguish what div was clicked within the repeated data rows?

Comment: Thanks again, had a try with the event handler and still same results, works for first div in the record set displayed but nothing for the remainder. i will try to post the html so you can see what i mean about the source once the page loads the data from the database, i have read about this problem all over with no solutions found, thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: perfect...tweaked to fit my task but the thought path was there thanks to you...many thanks and now i can let my hair grow back. Ed